# What is the cartesian equation of the Rhodenea/Rose Curve, $r=\cos k\theta$?

Tags: geometry

The question revolves around the Rhodonea curve, AKA rose curve. The polar equation given for the curve is 
$$r=\cos k \theta$$

Can anyone show me a way of finding a general rectangular coordinate equation for the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Expand $\cos k\theta$ as a polynomial in $\cos\theta$, replace each $\cos\theta$ by $x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $r$ by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and you are done. For example, if $k=4$, $$\cos 4\theta=8\cos^4\theta-8\cos^2\theta+1$$ hence $r=\cos4\theta$ is equivalent to $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=8\frac{x^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-8\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+1$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $k=1$, it is easy.

$$ r=\cos (\theta) \implies  r^2= r\cos (\theta) \implies x^2 + y^2 = x $$

For $k=2$ we expand $$ \cos( 2\theta ) = \cos ^2 ( \theta ) - \sin ^2 ( \theta )$$ to get 
$$ r=\cos (2\theta) \implies  r^2= r\cos (2\theta) \implies x^2 + y^2 = r(\frac {x^2}{r^2}-\frac  {y^2}{r^2})$$

$$\implies x^2 + y^2 = \frac {x^2 -y^2}{ \sqrt {x^2 + y^2  } }$$
Now you get the picture.

For larger values of $k$ we need to expand  $ \cos ( k\theta)$ and go from there.